# Is there software I can load on my web servers to know how much of my traffic is going to china?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have 15 VMs on Google Cloud and would like to know which one is causing my egress data to china.

How can I tell which one is doing the all that traffic? It has probably been hacked and would like to fix it.

Comment: I would open a case with google and ask them to assist you.  Provide them as much detail as you can.   If you have control over egress traffic policies, then you should limit outbound access to networks you trust in the mean time.

Comment: too bad you can't see traffic stats per vm.

Comment: Feel free to open a feature request through [GCE issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/list) with your use case details.

Comment: http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/

Answer (score 1):

Google does not provide this feature built in to GCE. However it is possible for you to add third party software to your instances that will track this. For example you could [Argus](https://www.qosient.com/argus/) or similar software.

Comment: NIce! Are there others?

Comment: I've never used them, but a bit of googling finds bandwidthd, darkstat, and the netflow or sflow ecosystems.